# Is it possible to use CrystalReports from unmanaged C++?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to use CrystalReports from an unmanaged C++ application.  I've been trying to work with a C# DLL with ComVisible set to True that wraps CR functions, but I haven't gotten that to work yet.  I'm wondering if I can skip C# entirely and just use CR from unmanaged C++.  The latest CR version I have is CR XI (11).

Comment: If crystal reports has a COM interface or a .dll (with a .h and preferrably a .lib), yes you can.

Comment: We use it from unmanaged C++ through a C# COM interop wrapper.

Comment: You don't have to go through .NET if the Crystal Reports exposes a standard COM interface and you have a typelib (a .TLB or a .DLL that contains a typelib). You can use it directly from unmanaged code (use #import on that typelib). If it's usable from .NET it should be usable directly from C/C++.

Comment: I have a com interop wrapper I can use, but I was hoping that a COM object is supplied already that I can use directly, and that someone could give me its name.